# Unable to install react-navigation-header-buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I had installed an old version before,but i want to upgrade to version 8, but I dont know how to face these errors

these are the current errors i am facinh

```
   npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: fyp@1.0.0
    npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@3.5.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
    npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native@"~3.5.0" from react-navigation@3.11.1   
    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation
    npm ERR!     react-navigation@"^3.11.1" from the root project
    npm ERR!   peer @react-navigation/native@"^3.1.1" from react-navigation-drawer@1.2.1
    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation-drawer
    npm ERR!     react-navigation-drawer@"~1.2.1" from react-navigation@3.11.1  
    npm ERR!     node_modules/react-navigation
    npm ERR!       react-navigation@"^3.11.1" from the root project
    npm ERR!   1 more (react-navigation-stack)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! react-navigation-header-buttons@"8.0.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @react-navigation/native@6.0.10       
    npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
    npm ERR!   peer @react-navigation/native@">=5" from react-navigation-header-buttons@8.0.0
    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-navigation-header-buttons
    npm ERR!     react-navigation-header-buttons@"8.0.0" from the root project  
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
```

Comment: try "npm install --legacy-peer-deps"

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (got the solution):

install a lower version of react-navigation-header-button. version 6 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your package, you have **@react-navigation/native** version **3.5.0**.

Try to upgrade @react-navigation/native version to **>=5** using

`npm i @react-navigation/native@latest` or `npm i @react-navigation/native@version_you_want(>=5)`

Then you can use **react-navigation-header-buttons** to version **8.0.0**

Or as an alternative

You can use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` if you can not have to upgrade **@react-navigation/native** package